# How to get a variable loaded from .Xresources?

Tags: python, xlib

I'm using Regolith which loads a bunch of Xresources, with variables like `i3-wm.font: typeface_wm` in some Xresources file. As far as I understand, these should be loaded into to X11 window system, which could be read from there. How can I get this value in a python script, without needing to parse the files myself?

I found the `python3-xlib` module, which I suppose should be able to do this, but I couldn't really make head nor tails from it ... I understand that Xlib is pretty low level and complicated, but I am really hoping there is an `Xlib.get_resource("i3-wm.font")` like command that can get me the resources I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this seems complicated!

I found some random code on github [here](https://github.com/WhatNodyn/Pyxr/blob/master/pyxr/pyxr.py) that has some clues, though.  The distilled version to allow for just reading is:

```
import Xlib
from Xlib.Xatom import RESOURCE_MANAGER, STRING

res_prop = Xlib.display.Display().screen().root.get_full_property(RESOURCE_MANAGER, STRING)
res_kv = (line.split(':', 1) for line in res_prop.value.decode().split('\n'))
res_dict = {kv[0]: kv[1].strip() for kv in res_kv if len(kv) == 2}
```

Though keep in mind this just grabs the entire db and shoves it into a dict so you can look up exact keys. In particular, it does none of the globbing that the rest of X pays attention to.  It should be enough to get you started, however.  In particular `res_dict['i3-wm.font']` will get that for you.

Comment: Thanks for digging up the info! I had to `from Xlib.display import Display` and change the `res_prop` line accordingly to make it work, but it does solve the issue. My workaround was using subprocess to call `xrdb -query`. Judging from what you needed to do with the output, the result is a bit similar: https://github.com/regolith-linux/i3-next-workspace/blob/cb469bae4d338ea9463985d66f3d89296be7a87a/i3-next-workspace#L23.

Comment: Thanks, it did take some digging, but what motivated me was that it was irksome to think that with all the power of python and libs, we still had to shell out and run `xrdb`... what's it doing that we can't do?  So now I know... and you don't have to depend on xrdb being installed.